# How to bind data dynamically to RadioButtonList in asp:repeater using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to make a MCQ test paper like following:

1. question1

   radiobuttonlist with values ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4
2. question2

   radiobuttonlist with values ans5,ans6,ans7,ans8

All the values of answers and questions must be retrieved from database.

Comment: This is too broad for Stack Overflow, voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one straightforward example: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/072701-1.shtml

Here's links to many more: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22radio+button%22+asp.net+databinding